# Is $δ=δ(x)$ a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis

If a real function $f:ℝ→ℝ$ is twice differentiable at a point $x$, then the first derivative must be continuous at $x$, and assuming $f′(x)>0$, then there exist $δ>0$ such that $f′(y)>0 $ for all $y∈(x−δ,x+δ)$, then on this interval $f$ must be increasing. Repeating this process for all $x$, we conclude that $δ$ is a function of $x$

Assuming that this function is analytic (the stronger form). I am asking if $δ=δ(x)$ is a continuous function in $x$.

If no, then what are the conditions on the function $f$ such that the above property holds true.

Comment: You have not defined $\delta$ uniquely as a function of $x$. For example, if $f(x)=x$, then one can take $\delta=1$ for $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $\delta=2$ for $x\not\in\mathbb{Q}$, which is not continuous (obviously).

Comment: @GHfromMO: Did you mean that we must add some thing about the set of $x$.

Comment: Note also that on any compact interval $I\subset\mathbb{R}$ you can choose $\delta=\delta(I)$ to be constant, since $f'(x)$ is positive and uniformly continuous on $I$.

Comment: No, I meant that for a given $x$, infinitely many positive $\delta$'s work (if $\delta$ is ok than any smaller $\delta$ is also ok), so it is not clear what you mean by $\delta(x)$.

Comment: @GHfromMO: It can be considered as one of those reals which I assume depends on $x$

Comment: Then trivially the answer to your question is no. For any positive valued function, there is a smaller positive valued non-continuous function. See my first remark.

Comment: You may want to see also [MR1745893 (2000m:54014)](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1745893) Enayat, Ali *[$\delta$ as a continuous function of $x$ and $\epsilon$](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2589436)*. Amer. Math. Monthly **107** (2000), no. 2, 151–155.

Comment: And [MR1837868](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1837868) De Marco, Giuseppe *[For every $\epsilon$ there continuously exists a $\delta$](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2695800)*.Amer. Math. Monthly **108** (2001), no. 5, 443–444.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$\delta(x)$ (defined as the maximum of appropriate $\delta$'s) is even 1-Lip (for any $f$). Indeed, if $|x-y|=a$, then $\delta(y)\geqslant \delta(x)-a$, since $(y-c,y+c)\subset (x-\delta(x),x+\delta(x))$ for $c=\max(\delta(x)-a,0)$. Analogously $\delta(x)\geqslant \delta(y)-a$ and therefore $|\delta(x)-\delta(y)|\leqslant a$.

Comment: I guess you meant that $\delta(x)$ is the supremum of all $\delta$'s that work for a given $x$. The problem is that the OP has not defined $\delta(x)$.

Comment: @GHfromMO yes, I understood her this way

Answer (score 5):

Smoothness of $f$ is a distraction here. Let us assume that $f$ is continuously differentiable (and we only need this because we **want** to talk about $f'$, not for any good reason), so that $f'$ exists and is continuous. Then $B : =\{x \mid f'(x) \leq 0\}$ is a closed set, and the largest valid choice for $\delta(x)$ is just $d(x,B)$.

For any set $A$, the function $x \mapsto d(x,A)$ is a $1$-Lipschitz function, by the triangle inequality for metrics. So, essentially, we already get that $\delta$ can be chosen as nice as possible if we only require enough about $f$ to make $\delta$ well-definable.

Just for completeness, if we don't require $\delta(x)$ to be the maximal feasible value, we could make $\delta$ as nasty as we want, e.g. by moving to $\bar\delta$ where $\bar\delta(x) = \delta(x)$ if $x \in Z$ and $\bar\delta(x) = \frac{1}{2}\delta(x)$ if $x \notin Z$ for some horrible $Z$.

Comment: Probably better not to use $\delta'$ for a new function when we're discussing differentiability.

Comment: @LSpice Bah, non-ambiguous notation is for pansies. Joking. I fixed this.